# call perl anonymous subroutine whose reference is maintained in a hash

Tags: perl, hash, subroutine

How do i call an perl anonymous subroutine whose reference is maintained in a hash ?

Here is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -W

use strict;
use warnings 'FATAL';
use diagnostics;
use utf8;


sub fn {
  my $href = $_[0];

  my %h = %{ $href };

  print %h;

  my $cref = $h{'p'};

  &$cref();
}


fn p => sub { print "inside anon function\n" };


1;
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what exactly you are trying to do ... ?  The shown program fails, per `Can't use string ("p") as a HASH ref ...` .  Can you state in words what you want?

Comment: As for what you do say, `$h{key_with_sub}->();` ... is that all you need?

Comment: @zdim thanks for your reply. the goal is to call the anonymous subroutine. what i expect is that ```&$cref()``` should work.

Comment: You do not pass a hash ref. You are passing just a list. And then you only use the first element of that list.

Comment: "_call the anonymous subroutine_"  --- OK, that's just about what I got, but I don't see in what exact context.  Once that code reference (the "anonymous sub") is passed around it winds up in a variable somewhere; then you just say `$var_with_coderef->()`, so `->()` calls the sub. See my other comment for one example, where the sub would be stored in a hash under the key `key_with_sub` (so earlier you'd have `$hash{key_with_sub} = sub { ... }`).  Have a look through [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) if you haven't; next up is `perlref`

Comment: @zdim i am aware of what you write, however i'm trying to understand the error, 

    Can't use string ("p") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at ./hashfn.pl line 13.
    main::fn("p", CODE(0x563b62a78578)) called at ./hashfn.pl line 24

Comment: OK. So: what you pass to your function is a list, as @dgw said, of: `p`, and the anon sub `sub {...}` (which is just a reference, a scalar). In the sub you take the first argument (`$_[0]`) so that's `p`, which is a mere string, just a letter. Then you try to "dereference" it into a hash (`%{ $href }`) -- well, it's not a reference ... that's the error at which the program exits. Why do you tnink that `p` is a hashref?

Comment: Also note that the "fat comma" (`=>`) effectively quotes that "bare" `p` that you have.  This is what `=>` operator does, apart from being a fancy-looking comma, so that  `p => 1` is equivalent to `"p" => 1`. Without that you couldn't have just `p` (a "bareword"), it would have to be under quotes (like `'p'`, or some other form of quoting).

Comment: ... and `"p" => 1` is the same as `"p", 1` (a list). See it [in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator)

Comment: @zdim 'p' is not a hashref. guess i missed the list assignment to a hash instead of a scalar. thanks for your time.

Comment: "_list assignment to a hash_"  --- yeah, that would've worked.  (I see now what you may have wanted).  Comments: 1) Can't nicely print a `%hash`. Either iterate over keys or use a module, `Data::Dumper`, `Data::Dump`, etc 2) no need for `1;` at the end; that's needed in modules

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sub expects to be passed a hash reference, but you don't pass a hash reference. You pass a string (`p`) and a code ref. That's because

```
fn p => sub { print "inside anon function\n" };
```

is the same as

```
fn "p", sub { print "inside anon function\n" };
```

Fix:

```
sub fn {
   my %h = @_;
   my $cref = $h{p};
   $cref->();
}

fn p => sub { print "inside anon function\n" };
```

That builds the hash on the inside of the sub. If you wanted to build the hash on the outside and pass a reference to it, it would look like this:

```
sub fn {
   my $href = $_[0];
   my $cref = $href->{p};
   $cref->();
}

fn { p => sub { print "inside anon function\n" } };
```

I avoided making a useless copy of the hash (`my %h = %{ $href };`).

---

`&$cref()` (but not `&$cref`) is fine too. I just prefer the arrow notation.